# Build VSTS extension azure webapp authentication JWT token validation failed

Tags: azure, authentication, web-applications, azure-devops, jwt

I am trying to build a  VSTS extension that can communicate to azure web app. I was able to achieve this but without authentication. I was referring to the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/vsts/extend/develop/auth#calling-rest-apis-from-your-extension).

I took the token generated from browser i.e console.log(token) and verified it in [this website](https://jwt.io/).

It says Invalid signature.

The logic mentioned for .Net framework to validate the generated token does not work.  It gives me following error:

> IDX10500: Signature validation failed. Unable to resolve
>   SecurityKeyIdentifier: 'SecurityKeyIdentifier
>
> (
>
> IsReadOnly = False,
>
> Count = 1,
>
> Clause[0] = X509ThumbprintKeyIdentifierClause(Hash = 0xA0EBDCCF933FEE9F878C82A5157CFDDEEFD5D19A)
>
> )
>
> ',
>
> token: '{"typ":"JWT","alg":"RS256",......

Comment: Same issue for me and submit a feedback https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/189687/vsts-jwt-auth-token-issue.html

Comment: What's your code to get the token? Make sure the code is `VSS.getAppToken()` instead of `VSS.getAccessToken()`.

Comment: Thanks @starian chen-MSFT this helped resolve the issue.

Answer (score 1):

Replace `VSS.getAccessToken()` to `VSS.getAppToken()` can solve the issue.